# Cannot create scratch with namespace

Tags: salesforcedx, scratch-org, namespace

I've linked namespace, set up `sfdx-project.json`

```
{
    "packageDirectories": 
    [
        {
        "path": "force-app",
        "default": true
        }
    ],
    "namespace": "vpv",
    "sfdcLoginUrl": "https://login.salesforce.com",
    "sourceApiVersion": "47.0"
}
```

But when I try to create scratch I've got an error:

> We don’t recognize this namespace: vpv. Did you register it in your Dev Hub org?

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Of course I've linked namespace

Comment: Well, the message points to that process not having worked or that you are connected to the wrong dev hub... So double-check.

Comment: sdfx force:org:list says me that my DevHub is (D) - default. What can be wrong with process?

Comment: Your dev hub can be set to something else for the current directory, or based on the CLI args you used. So, it can be in ./.sfdx/sfdx-config.json under the "defaultdevhubusername" key, or it can be via the  --targetdevhubusername or -v flag on the CLI command

Comment: sfdx force:org:create -a PkgScratch -s -f config/project-scratch-def.json -v DevHub where DevHub is alias of default org. Unfortunately, there is still no results - I'v got the same error :(

Comment: That just points back to Keith's original suggestion. Either you did not successfully complete the namespace linking process, or you did complete it but in a different Dev Hub. You can verify by looking at the Namespace Registries records in your Dev Hub, which should list your namespace if linked.